# Is it possible to have a validation error less than train error for a while followed by the reverse behaviour?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, cross-validation, tensorflow

I am solving for a **regression** (using tensorflow's DNNRegressor) problem. When I sampled out 20% data (randomly) and divided it further into train-eval (90-10%, random but mutually exclusive), I observed the following graphs-
[image: train (orange) + eval (blue) loss against steps on x axis]

[image: eval loss (blue) against steps on x axis]

Here, blue line corresponds to eval set loss and orange line is for train loss. The total length of data is nearly 4.8 million rows, thus 20% being nearly 1 million data points. How to interpret this behavior?

Comment: Why are there two graphs?

Comment: just highlighting the eval loss separately to show where it starts becoming asymptotic.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally normal. Usually the training loss is computed as weight updates are being done. Then when the whole epoch is finished the validation loss is computed. The validation loss will thus be lower than training loss at first because it has the unfair advantage of being computed after all the weight updates for that epoch.

Once the validation loss has reached its minimum, the training loss can continue to decrease. There is no point in continuing training past this point.

Comment: but then a validation set will always have the advantage you mentioned, then why does this behavior not show up that often? also, why does the validation loss stabilize here whereas the train loss keeps decreasing? shouldn't the former rather increase, showing over-fitting traits?

Comment: Whats the scale on the x axis? The advantage diminishes over time. You dont have an over fitting problem in these graphs. If you train for even longer or use a bigger network you are likely to see some overftting.